# str.__getslice__ is not working as expected with negative stop

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, indexing, python-internals

I was trying to run following code in python 2.7:

```
foo = "python is awesome"
print foo[10:16]
print foo.__getslice__(10,16)
print foo[10:-1]
print foo.__getslice__(10,-1)
```

all except the last one printed `"awsome"`. but `foo.__getslice__(10,-1)` returned an empty string. Why is it so?

Comment: This is not specific to strings; you get the same behaviour with `foo = list(foo)`. Also, for both `str` and `list`, `help(*.__getslice__)` explicitly mentions that negative indices are not supported. `foo[slice(10, -1)]` works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

string is implemented in [c](/questions/tagged/c) so the answer isn't that straight-forward to understand if you don't know much about [c](/questions/tagged/c) and the [python-c-api](/questions/tagged/python-c-api), but I try my best anyway:

If you call `__getslice__` directly you'll use [`string_slice`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#L1129-L1148):

```c
static PyObject *
string_slice(PyStringObject *a, Py_ssize_t i, Py_ssize_t j)
     /* j -- may be negative! */
{
    if (i < 0)
        i = 0;
    if (j < 0)
        j = 0; /* Avoid signed/unsigned bug in next line */
    if (j > Py_SIZE(a))
        j = Py_SIZE(a);
    if (i == 0 && j == Py_SIZE(a) && PyString_CheckExact(a)) {
        /* It's the same as a */
        Py_INCREF(a);
        return (PyObject *)a;
    }
    if (j < i)
        j = i;
    return PyString_FromStringAndSize(a->ob_sval + i, j-i);
}
```

Here `i` is the start index and `j` is the stop index. In case stop is smaller than zero it will be set to `0` (`if (j < 0) j = 0;`), then because it's smaller than the start it will be set to start (`if (j < i) j = i;`). So you end up with start=10 and stop=10, which is just an empty string.

But if you use `[]` you'll call [`string_subscript`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#L1296-L1356) (I'll just include the relevant parts of that method):

```c
static PyObject*
string_subscript(PyStringObject* self, PyObject* item)
{
    /* ... */
    if (PySlice_Check(item)) {
        Py_ssize_t start, stop, step, slicelength, cur, i;
        /* ... */

        if (_PySlice_Unpack(item, &start, &stop, &step) < 0) {
            return NULL;
        }
        slicelength = _PySlice_AdjustIndices(PyString_GET_SIZE(self), &start,
                                            &stop, step);

        /* ... */
        if (step == 1) {
            return PyString_FromStringAndSize(
                PyString_AS_STRING(self) + start,
                slicelength);
        }
        /* ... */
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

This **correctly** adjusts the indices with `_PySlice_AdjustIndices` (it's like [`PySlice_AdjustIndices`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/slice.html#c.PySlice_AdjustIndices)). That function will convert the stop of -1 to a stop of `len(string) - 1`:

> **Py_ssize_t PySlice_AdjustIndices(Py_ssize_t length, Py_ssize_t *start, Py_ssize_t *stop, Py_ssize_t step)**
>
> Adjust start/end slice indices assuming a sequence of the specified length. Out of bounds indices are clipped in a manner consistent with the handling of normal slices.

The function that is actually called may be different from that function. But I believe that the documentation applies to both.

---

But you shouldn't normally call `__*__` methods directly. So I don't know if that's a bug or intended use in Python (it could be an optimized function for certain kinds of slicing for all I know).

However [`__getslice__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__) was deprecated a long time ago - better stay away from it completly.

Comment: This is a great answer, despite the fact that the language names are disconcerting tag links :)